# Unfreeze Epson Perfection 2480 flat-bed scanner from GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, arch-linux, scanner, sane

So I have been happily using my `Epson Perfection 2480 Photo` for years from `Microsoft Windows 7`, `Microsoft Windows 10`, and various `GNU/Linux` distributions, and it's still going strong. Occasionally, for mysterious reasons it freezes, and when it does the only way I can get it to reset, which is indicated by a brief activation of the scanning arm, is to plug it into a `Microsoft Windows` system. I have found no way to reset it solely from `GNU/Linux`, which is currently my preferred operating system.

This is a summary of my `Arch Linux` `SANE` configuration:

I've been using for a few years now `Arch Linux` with `SANE` installed, then `iscan-plugin-gt-f500` from the AUR such that I can get reports like this:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `snapscan:libusb:002:004' is a EPSON EPSON Scanner flatbed scanner
```

When it's seized, I get reports like this:

```
$ scanimage -A
Output format is not set, using pnm as a default.
[snapscan] Cannot open firmware file /usr/share/sane/snapscan/your-firmwarefile.bin.
[snapscan] Edit the firmware file entry in snapscan.conf.
scanimage: open of device snapscan:libusb:002:004 failed: Invalid argument
```

and then no amount of unplugging of the scanner and even rebooting of Arch gets my `Epson Perfection 2480 Photo` reset such that I can scan again. The only thing that works is to briefly plug it into a `Microsoft Windows` machine. I had the same snag in previous years when I was using `esfw41.bin` instead of `iscan-plugin-gt-f500`.  How can I avoid this, and reset it from `GNU/Linux`?

Comment: Most USB scanners need a firmware upload in order to work http://snapscan.sourceforge.net/ The __bin__ file can be found in the windows drivers coming with your scanner. (It's an older page but you stated _for years_. Peace.

Comment: @vssher, no, the (old) firmware `esfw41.bin` that I mentioned also gave the same problem.

Comment: Assuming that you tried the usual stuff (removing usb, power cable power on, reconnect power), does the freeze happen with Sane only, or also with Iscan? Did you try the test version of Vuescan (which can help deblocking)?